# First sums of the Thue-Morse sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, combinatorics-on-words

Let $t_n$ denote the $n^{\rm th}$ element of the Thue-Morse sequence, i.e., $t_n$ begins
$$
0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,\ldots
$$
The first differences of this series are present in the OEIS as entry [A029883](http://oeis.org/search?q=A029883&language=english&go=Search). This sequence begins
$$
1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0,\ldots
$$
I am however interested in the *first sums* of the Thue-Morse sequence, i.e., the sequence $s_n$ such that $s_n=t_n+t_{n-1}$ for all $n\geq1$. I have found no reference to this sequence in the OEIS. For info, $s_n$ begins:
$$
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, \ldots
$$
It is easy to find some ''basic'' properties of this sequence based on those of $t_n$, but I was wondering whether there have already been some more in-depth studies about it, like for the ''first differences'' sequence.

Comment: can you find info about $s_n$ based on binary representation of $n$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Can you elaborate?

Comment: The Thue-Morse sequence $t_n = digitsum_2(n) \mod 2$ where $digitsum_b(n)$ is the digital sum of integer $n$ in base $b$.

A property of digital sums is that 
$$digitsum_b(x + y) = digitsum_b(digitsum_b(x) + digitsum_b(y))$$

Try using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the Thue-Morse sequence $(t_n)_{n\ge0}$ is defined by the recurrence:

- $t_0=0$;
- $t_{2n}=t_n$; and
- $t_{2n+1}=1-t_n$.

Thus, to calculate $s_n=t_n+t_{n-1}$ it is natural to separate the cases when $n$ is even and odd.

If $n=2k$ then $s_n=t_{2k}+t_{2k-1}=t_k+(1-t_{k-1})=1+(t_k-t_{k-1})$, so this is essentially the same as the *first difference* sequence.

If $n=2k+1$ then $s_n=t_{2k+1}+t_{2k}=(1-t_k)+t_k=1$ is constant, so this is uninteresting.

Thus, my guess is that studying the *first sum* sequence is essentially equivalent to studying the *first difference* sequence, which is why there isn't much literature on it.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Warning**. I considered the sequence $t_n + t_{n+1}$ instead of $t_n + t_{n-1}$, which is not defined for $n = 0$, but it is easy to make the translation.

It is shown in $[1]$ that the shift of a [$q$-automatic sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_sequence) is $q$-automatic and that the sum of two $q$-automatic sequences is $q$-automatic.
Since $t_n$ is $2$-automatic, it follows that $s_n$ is $2$-automatic.

In this specific case, it is not too difficult to obtain the corresponding automata. Here is the automaton for $t_n$

$\qquad$[image: Automaton for t_n]

and the one for the shifted sequence $t_{n+1}$ (the initial state is $1$)

$\qquad$[image: Automaton for t_{n+1}]

Combinining the two automata gives

$\qquad$[image]

which leads to the automaton for $s_n$ by adding the outputs (the initial state is $1$)

$\qquad$[image]

For instance, for $n = 21$, the binary expansion is $10101$, and since $1 \cdot 10101 = 4$, one gets $s_{21} = 2$. Indeed,
\begin{align}
t &= 01101001100101101001011001101001 \dotsm \\
s &= 121110121011121110111\color{red}{2}101211101 \dotsm
\end{align}
You can certainly find many properties of $s_n$ from the knowledge of this automaton.

EDIT. In particular, if $n$ is even, then $s_n = 1$. If you consider only the odd positions, that is, the sequence $s_{2k+1}$, you obtain the [OEIS sequence A316826](https://oeis.org/A316826)
$$
210201210120210201202101 \dotsm
$$
obtained by removing the initial $3$ in the image of $3$ by iteration of the morphism $0 \to 02$, $1 \to 1012$, $2 \to 102012$ and $3 \to 32$.

$[1]$ S. Lehr, Sums and rational multiples of $q$-automatic sequences are $q$-automatic. *Theoret. Comput. Sci.* **108** (1993), no. 2, 385--391.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Does this approach make it possible to get a recurrence relation for s_n? Note that for the first differences sequence a_n we have a_4n = a_n, a_{4n+1} = a_{2n+1}, a_{4n+2} = 0, and a_{4n+3} = - a_{2n+1}.